# Array of objects piped into my custom filter always shows as length of zero

Tags: angular, ionic2

Am looping over an array of object in my view like this (without the pipe I get the whole list displayed):

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor= "let category  of (productCategories | onlyhomecategory) " >
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
      {{category.title}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

I am feeding the array into a custom pipe called `onlyhomecategory` to filter out any categories that don't have a `home` property like this:

```
import {Injectable, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'onlyhomecategory'

})
@Injectable()
export class OnlyHomeCategories {
  transform(productCategories: any[] , args: any[]) {

    console.log(productCategories.length);  //retuns 0

    //If I hard-code/mock the array, pipe works as expected.

    return productCategories.filter(category => category.home);
  }
}
```

This is the shape of how the array looks like:

```
[
  {
    home: 1,
    title: "Greevy Swaney",
    text: "Find the right area",
  },
  {
    home: 2,
    title: "Taney Wearx",
    text: "Choose the right system",
  },
  {
    title: "Tine rider",
  },
  {
  title: "Shade",
  }
];
```

This is the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProductCategories {
  data: any = null;
  constructor(public http: Http) {}

  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

This is the view component:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core'
import {ProductCategories} from '../../providers/product-categories/product-categories'
import {OnlyHomeCategories} from '../../pipes/only-home-categories'

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/product-category/product-category.html',
  pipes: [OnlyHomeCategories]
})

export class ProductCategoryPage {
  public productCategories = [];

  constructor(public nav: NavController, private prodCat: ProductCategories)     {

this.prodCat.load()
.then(data => {
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.productCategories.push(data[key]);
    }
  }
  console.log(`this.productCategories.length: ${this.productCategories.length}`); // this return correct length
});
```

}
}

Am not sure where am going wrong. Without the custom pipe, my view shows all the categories but I can't seem to get the pipe to work.

Comment: I guess this is because it is empty at the time it is passed to the pipe. Can you show the code that sets `productCategories`?

Comment: How is the array assigned to `productCategories`?

Comment: Am console.logging the array in the class of the view to prove it's not empty and it returns a length. Problem occurs when the array is passed to the Pipe. Also, if the array is empty, then it wouldn't also work when I don't use a Pipe, right?

Comment: How is the array assigned to productCategories? From a service, which is imported into the class of the view. When I console.log from both the service and component, I get the correct array length.

Comment: It might be a timing issue. But without at least seeing the code (and short of having a Plunker that allows to reproduce) others can only make assumptions.

Comment: Have you declared the Pipes array in your component?   pipes: [OnlyhomecategoryPipe]

Comment: Just a hint. There is no need to add `@Injectable()` when there is `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, or `@Pipe()`. These include `@Injectable()` already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular doesn't monitor array content changes. Because you initialize productCategories with an empty array and later add elements to this same array, change detection doesn't detect the change and doesn't invoke the pipe again.

**pure: false**

You can make the pipe impure, so it gets called every time change detection runs, not only when the pipe input changes

```ts
@Pipe({
  name: 'onlyhomecategory',
  pure: false

})
export class OnlyHomeCategories {
  transform(productCategories: any[] , args: any[]) {

    console.log(productCategories.length);  //retuns 0

    return productCategories.filter(category => category.home);
  }
}
```

*disadvantages*:

Making a pipe impure has performance implications, because the pipe is called a lot (every time Angular runs change detection).
To not cause this too much harm, ensure that the pipe doesn't do expensive work. For example try to cache the result of expensive calculations as long as the relevant inputs haven't changed. You need to keep track of previous and new values yourself.

**different object**

You can also make Angular detect the change, by not only adding content but creating a new - different - array.

```ts
this.prodCat.load()
.then(data => {
  let arr = [];
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      arr.push(data[key]);
    }
  }
  this.productCategories = arr;
  console.log(`this.productCategories.length: ${this.productCategories.length}`); // this return correct length
});
```

*disadvantages*:

If the array is large, copying can be expensive.

**Hint**

If you modify an array that already contains values you can create a copy using `slice()`:

```ts
this.prodCat.load()
.then(data => {
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.productCategories.push(data[key]);
    }
  }
  this.productCategories = this.productCategories.slice();
  console.log(`this.productCategories.length: ${this.productCategories.length}`); // this return correct length
});
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kBTU238Oa9P8LIUhj14J?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. Which would you recommend? using pure false or pointing the this.productCategories to a new array?

Comment: That depends on the details. In your case I would definitely go for creating a copy. You start with a new array and add more elements only once. The only additional work to do is create a new empty array once. Otherwise with an impure pipe, the pipe is run thousands of times and that sums up a lot. If you would update the `productCategories` a lot and it contains lots of elements, you would need to copy the array after each modification to get a new instance. This can become expensive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the `args: any[]`
Look at this example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    import { Flyer } from './heroes';

    @Pipe({ name: 'flyingHeroes' })
    export class FlyingHeroesPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(allHeroes:Flyer[]) {
        return allHeroes.filter(hero => hero.canFly);
      }
    }
```